# Jupyter / Ipython Notebook Html Page View

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I installed Ipython Notebook but html page does not seem correct. Tabs and links do not seem correctly installled. You may see the screenshot samples as attached. Can anyone advise how I can fix this ? [image: 1st screenshot]

[image: 2nd screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I am sure,  it is just internet connection trouble, not IPython (Jupyter) Notebook. But chech up information about [Browser Compatibility](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/install/install.html?highlight=quickstart).

Browser Compatibility. The IPython notebook is officially supported on the following browsers:

```
Chrome ≥ 13,
Safari ≥ 5,
Firefox ≥ 6.
```

The is mainly due to the notebook’s usage of WebSockets and the flexible box model.

The following browsers are unsupported:

```
Safari < 5,
Firefox < 6,
Chrome < 13.
```

Opera (any): CSS issues, but execution might work

```
Internet Explorer < 10,
Internet Explorer ≥ 10 (same as Opera).
```

Using Safari with HTTPS and an untrusted certificate is known to not work (websockets will fail).

Comment: I do  not have a problem with internet connection. Also, checked browser compatibility,  I use the last version of firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an issue with your cached browser data conflicting with the latest update from Ipython Notebook to Jupyter. Try clearing all web browser history and restarting your browser to see if it helps. Perhaps an incognito window may also help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a registry problem on Windows:
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7024