# Jupyter / Ipython not displaying correctly in browser

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have installed Anaconda python 3.4 distribution for windows 64. This was a fresh install today of all components. I am super excited to start learning python. However, when I run 'ipython notebook' the browser page has formatting issues (see image in first link below). This occurs on firefox, chrome, and IE. On IE, the 'compatibility view' icon pops up. This is what I have tried:

- updated conda and anaconda
- Installed jupyter ('conda update jupyter' couldn't find the package)
- refreshed browser with ctrl + F5
- Checked that chrome and firefox are up-to-date.

There are others who have reported a similar problem, but no solutions have been given yet:

[Jupyter / Ipython Notebook Html Page View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020556/jupyter-ipython-notebook-html-page-view)

[Jupyter webpages not displaying properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899764/jupyter-webpages-not-displaying-properly)

Seems like it should be a simple fix, but I haven't figured it out after hours of messing around. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

UPDATE #1
Following Bubbafat advice, I opened the page using incognito, opened the debugging console, and refreshed the page (ctrl + F5).  There were errors with the Stylesheet:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-css: "http://localhost:8888/static/components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css?v=9b2c8d3489227115310662a343fce11c".

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-css: "http://localhost:8888/static/style/style.min.css?v=b2822da270f572199d71df9279c2c9e8".

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-css: "http://localhost:8888/custom/custom.css".
```

If anyone know how to fix this for Windows 7, I would greatly appreciate the advice.  The link in Bubbafat's comment is for linux and I don't know how to translate to windows. In addition, if there is an older version of anaconda that is known to work well with Windows 7 (perhaps before jupyter was rolled out) I could also downgrade. Any advice is appreciated.

UPDATE #2
Looking around on the web, I think my SOPHOS anti-virsus software might be the issue. Unfortunately, it is a company computer, so I'll need IT to turn it off.

Comment: On the surface is looks like missing CSS - try opening F12 debugging (in Chrome hit "F12" and it will open a debugging contsole) then move to the console view and refresh the page.  If there are missing resources or errors you should see details there.  Specifically I think style.min.css.<long random number> is missing - this might be discussed here:  https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did have a very similar issue on Windows recently. Some program has overwritten your mime type associations. For me it was Inkscape killing SVG by setting the mime type to application/svg.

Try this on terminal:

import mimetypes

mimetypes.guess('file.css')

You should get text/css. If you get application/css this is most likely your problem. My solution: Change back the mime type association. Start regedit and search for application/css in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. Replace it with text/css.

Please refer to this https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7024 for further reference.

Comment: That did it!  Had to refresh a bunch.  Thanks!